# How to determine if a string is a Mathematical statement in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, math, match

I have this string for an instance:

`"2 + 2 - 2"` and when evaluated it should return `int(2)`;

I'm looking for a function/parser witch can determine if anykind of math content is matched within a string. More examples:

```
"(2 + 2) / 2"
"(4 / 8) * 12"
"128 * 8"
```

Do not need to evaluate and calculate these Math expressions, just need a function witch will determine (`True/False` return values), if the statement is of this Math kind.

Is this possible with regex or something? Thanks!

Comment: Define "mathematical statement".

Comment: String witch contains any of math operands: /, *, +, -, except "=". I've handled that ...

Comment: Yes, define *"mathematical statement"*. At least, do you mean *"arithmetic statement"*?

Comment: Yes, that. I've done it now, thank you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php). For example, you can do this:

```
$result = INF;
try { 
  eval("$result=" + myMathExpression);  // Evaluate here
} catch (Exception $e) { 

} 
if($result != INF) echo("Expression is a valid mathematical expression.");
```

**Just be careful, because any PHP code will be evaluated!**

Comment: I guess he wants to evaluate if someone typed in a proper math expression. putting that straight into `eval()` is suicide.

Comment: I've used your example and it works. I know I'm leaving a security hole here regardings the "eval" function, but I'll take care about that later. :) Thank you.

Comment: "Taking care later" is never a good option. I still recommend using some kind of regular expression, like `/^[0-9\+\-\*\/()]+$/`, that checks if there are only valid characters. Later, you can then refine that, instead of leaving a gaping hole behind right now.

Comment: I'm writing a simple custom-code parser just to get an idea how it might work. This is my project just for testing these kinds of eniviroments and stuff. :)

Comment: Alright: If it doesn't get out in the open I won't complain. I just want to make sure, that everybody who sees this question is aware of the security implications of `evil()` ... errr ... `eval()`

Comment: Yes. I'm aware of that as well. :) My current knowledge about creating programming/scripting languages is not high, so if you have any other links or articles to recommend on this matter, please do so @twall. :) thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9196/discussion-between-commando-and-twall)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe run it as php on runtime and check that the responding value comes back as numeric. Take a look at this. http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: That sounds like a bad idea, given that you can execute arbitrary PHP this way.

Comment: yes, it's a little insecure, but with some regex wrapped around your input to test that they are entering numbers and only certain symbols it could be the best way to get a sum back.  might be handy also for extending into better math functions if that eventually becomes a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what type of expressions you will be parsing you could try to use regular expressions. Something like `^\d+\s*(\+|-|\*|\\)\s*\d+` should yield true if you are trying to validate the binary operators of `+`,`*`, `-` and `\`. So it would validate items such as `3 + 3`, `2 - 0`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a parser generator from XP-framework.
See [sample grammar](http://news.xp-framework.net/article/236/0000/00/00/) for calculator, which can be translated to PHP code.